# Is there a way to use Python, HTML, and JS to display the output of multiple functions on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

So I have a .py file (I'll call it `displayTest`) that imports other .py files and uses `init` to pass self and get data from these files. The `displayTest` file reads through a list of given messages and then runs a test to make sure all the messages are in a queue. I want the html page to display the output of a print statement using this py file.

This is what I have so far, using a template I found online. I'm not sure if I'd need Flask or JS to actually get this to work but if so I'd love some resources and advice!
[HTML + VScode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf6CM.png)

Here is a general view of one part of the file (I've changed things for it to be more generic)

```
class Test(test.TestCase):

    def test01_init(self):
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data, DATA)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.prev_data, DATA)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.time, 0.0)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.end_time, 400.0)

    def test01_reset(self):
        sys_sim.reset()
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data, DATA)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.prev_data, DATA)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.time, 0.0)
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.end_time, 400.0)

    def test02_advance_test(self):
        sys_sim.reset()
        sys_sim.advance()
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["DisplayMessage"], 1)

        msgids = list(range(256,273)) + [1000,1001,1002,1003]
        for msgid in msgids:
            while sys_sim.msg_app.display_message_expiration > 0:
                sys_sim.advance()
            sys_sim.advance()
            self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["DisplayMessage"], msgid)

    def test03_advance_msg_nav(self):
        sys_sim.reset()
        

        
        sys_sim.data["SCU_Current"] = 1
        sys_sim.advance()
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["StateNumber"], 1)

        
        while sys_sim.sim_time < 35.0:

            sys_sim.advance()

        
        sys_sim.data["Current 1"] = 1
        sys_sim.data["Current 2"] = 1
        sys_sim.data["Current 3"] = 1
        sys_sim.data["RCA_SW"] = "CO2"
        sys_sim.advance()
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["StateNumber"], 2)



        sys_sim.data["DIR"] = "UP"
        sys_sim.advance()
        sys_sim.data["MessageMode"] = "Status"
        sys_sim.data["DisplayMessage"] = 5027
        sys_sim.data["DIR"] = "UP"
        sys_sim.advance_sim()
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["MOTION"], "SHORT")
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.msg_app.response, "FWD")
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["MessageMode"], "Status")
        self.assertEqual(sys_sim.data["DisplayMessage"], 5028)
```

Comment: Use Flask to run Python as a webserver.

Comment: I'm using flask now, but wondering how to execute the code. When I try to use file(open'r ...), the module that I'm using in the .py file can't be located